# AngularJS ng-click with parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this line of code :

```
<input  type="button" ng-click="tableDelete()" name="delete" value="Delete">
```

and in tableDelete(), I would like to put a parameter : {{row.entity.id}} (the id of the button where I click in an array)

The problem is that if I put it like this, when I call my function tableDelete(var), var is undefined...

So here is my question : how can we pass parameters to a function through ng-click ?

Thank you

Comment: what do you want to pass to function? scope variable, static variable...?

Comment: Thank you, Adam Zuckerman fixed my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the handlebars.

```
<input  type="button" ng-click="tableDelete(row.entity.id)" name="delete" value="Delete">
```

Comment: OMG I'm going to kill my self. Thank you so much I've just lost so many time on this stupid thing :)

Comment: If you would mark it as the answer, I would be most appreciative.

Comment: yes sorry I had to wait 5 minutes (and I would vote up when I'll have more reputation ;) )